# Miniconda3 fails to install with error "python-3.7.1-h0371630_7/bin/python: not found"

Tags: python, ubuntu, miniconda

I am getting this error when installing Miniconda3 for Linux:

```
PREFIX=/data/ubuntu/miniconda3
installing: python-3.7.1-h0371630_7 ...
Miniconda3-latest-Linux-x86.sh: 373: Miniconda3-latest-Linux-x86.sh: /data/ubuntu/miniconda3/pkgs/python-3.7.1-h0371630_7/bin/python: not found
```

Why is it happening and what should I do for it?

```
whereis python
python: /usr/bin/python3.6m /usr/bin/python3.6 /usr/lib/python2.7 /usr/lib/python3.7 /usr/lib/python3.6 /etc/python3.6 /usr/local/lib/python3.6 /usr/share/python

echo $PATH
/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin:/usr/games:/usr/local/games:/snap/bin:/usr/bin/python3.6:/usr/lib/python3.7
```

Trying to install on Ubuntu AWS instance.

Comment: Well, do you find the python binary mentioned in the absolute path in the error?

Comment: @user8408080 well what does it mean? This path was created during the installation process so I would assume it should be part of the installation file?

Comment: Ah of course; my bad. Maybe there is a rights problem?

Comment: No, I gave all permissions to these folders...

Answer (score 1):

The reason is wrong architecture. Need to use Miniconda3-latest-Linux-x86_64.sh instead of Miniconda3-latest-Linux-x86.sh.